# How to find the biggest value in the pandas dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that shows the share of every disease from total diseases.
I want to find the country name which in that country AIDS is bigger than other diseases.
[image: Data]

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
df.index[df.AIDS.eq(df.drop('Total',1).max(1))]
```

Comment: I tried it and the output is : Index([], dtype='object', name='country')

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at pandas max function (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html)

Here you could get the max for each row, as is:

```
most_frequent_disease = df.drop(columns=['Total', 'Other']).max(axis=1)
```

Then you can create a condition to check wether AIDS is the most frequent disease, and apply it to your dataframe:

```
is_aids_most_frequent_disease = df.loc[:, 'A'].eq(most_frequent_disease)
df[is_aids_most_frequent_disease]
```

You could get the country name by using the `.index` at the end of the expression too.

Comment: I knew it, but I want the country name which in that country  AIDS is bigger than other disieases.